# Java, getter for array values (array dynamically defined)

Tags: java, arrays, object, inheritance

I have a series of `String[]` arrays which are list of words. Something like:

```
String[] ListOne = new String[100];
String[] ListTwo = new String[100];
/*And so on with other lists */

ListOne[0] = "word00";
ListOne[1] = "word01";
/*And so on till*/
ListLast[99] = "word 99 from last list";
```

Now I want a function for each list that, given a number returns the corresponding element (word):

```
public String GetFromListOne(int key) { return ListOne[key];}
```

Is there a way to avoid manually writing each of this getter functions?

In PHP, for example, I would just use the magic method `__call`,
or pass as an argument with the list name and reference it dynamically.

Is there a way to do something similar in Java?
Or an alternative strategy to achieve the same result?

Comment: Why can't your code just do `ListXXX[idx]`? Simpler. Smaller. Faster.

Comment: why not use lists[list_id][element_id]?

Comment: @jmendeth OP's asking a way to avoid creating `getListOneItem`, `getListTwoItem`, `getListThreeItem` and on...

Comment: What's more, I think you're not expressing the correct concept. Don't you mean having a list of `Entry` objects, each one having a `one`, `two` and `three` property?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza and I'm asking the OP why does he need those functions :) His code can directly do `ListOne[index]` or `Lists[1][index]` instead of `GetFromListOne(index)`. Simpler. Smaller. ... yeah you already know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into inheritance.

What you basically must do is define an interface (or extend a List class)

```
 public interface ListTest{
//**Gets keys from lists*//
GetFromListOne(int key);
}
```

then

```
public class Listone implements ListTest{

/** methods **//
GetFromListOne(int key);
/** methods **//
}
```

Have fun extending

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Comment: Simple and very well working. I used abstract class instead of interface, but that’s how I written my code. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 2 dimensional array, or a list of arrays and have your function take 2 parameters.  One for the array that you want and the other for the element in the array.

2 dimensional array:

```
String[][] ListN = new String[100,100];

String getFromList(int n, int key) {
    return ListN[n][key];
}
```

Or list of arrays:

```
List<String[]> listOfArrays = new ArrayList<String[]>();
listOfArrays.add(new String[100]);
listOfArrays.add(new String[100]);


String getFromList(int n, int key) {
    return listOfArrays.get(n)[key];
}
```

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this :) +1

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık `if ("sorcery".equals("code")) this.equals("sorcery")`

Comment: The only problem with this is if OP uses arrays of different nature, like `MyClass[] myClassArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Could you have a function that takes as input the key and the list number:

```
public String GetFromListOne(int list, int key) {
    switch(list):
       case 1:
           return ListOne[key];
           break;
       case 2:
           return ListTwo[key];
           break;
       ...
}
```

or even better make an array of arrays:

```
String[][] ListOfLists = new String[10];
ListOfLists[0] = new String[100];
...

public String GetFromList(int list, int key) {
    return ListOfLists[list][key];
}
```

Otherwise I don't know of a function to override like __call

Answer (score 0):

Based in the `__call` PHP method, you can achieve this implementing a method that receives the list and the index, and using generics you can get something like this.

```
public class Utility {
    public <T> T getElementFromArray(T[] array, int index) {
        if (index >= array.length || index < 0) return null;
        return array[index];
    }
}
```

The pitfall of this method is that can't be used for primitive array holders, like `int[]`. The solution for these cases would be using the wrapper classes for primitive types.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Utility u = new Utility();
    String[] ss = new String[2];
    ss[0] = "Hello";
    ss[1] = "world!";
    System.out.println(u.getElementFromArray(ss, 0));
    System.out.println(u.getElementFromArray(ss, 1));
    int[] ii = new int[2];
    ii[0] = 5;
    System.out.println(u.getElementFromArray(ii, 0)); //compile error
    //Solution: use wrapper classes
    Integer[] ii2 = new Integer[2];
    ii2[0] = 5;
    System.out.println(u.getElementFromArray(ii2, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String[] ListFour=new String[100];
   String[] ListTwentyThree=new String[100];
   String[] ListNine=new String[100];
   String[] ListOne=new String[100];

   Hashtable<Integer,String[]> yourlist=new Hashtable<Integer,String[]>();      
   yourlist.put(4, ListFour);
   yourlist.put(23, ListTwentyThree);
   yourlist.put(9, ListNine);
   yourlist.put(1, ListOne);
   System.out.println(yourlist.get(4)[5]);//fifth string in ListFour
   System.out.println(yourlist.get(23)[51]);//fifty first string in List23
    System.out.println(yourlist.get(9)[1]);//first stringin ListNine
```

another version:

```
   Hashtable<Object,String[]> yourlist=new Hashtable<Object,String[]>();        
   yourlist.put("two multiplied by two", ListFour);
   yourlist.put(23, ListTwentyThree);
   yourlist.put(0.03, ListNine);
   yourlist.put(true, ListOne);
   System.out.println(yourlist.get("two multiplied by two")[5]);//fifth string in ListFour
   System.out.println(yourlist.get(23)[51]);//fifty first string in List23
    System.out.println(yourlist.get(true)[1]);//first stringin ListNine
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
List<String[]> lists = new ArrayList<String[]>();

public String getFromLists(int key) {
  List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (String[] s: lists){
      res.add(s[key]);
  }    
  return res.get(key);
}
```

or better

```
public String getFromLists(int key) {
  return lists.get(key)[key];
}
```